# Persistent computed Oracle Virtual Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

For performance gain, I am looking to make persistence derived column by combination of few fields from same column.

I have explored about automated and virtual column, but didn't give proper solution to me. 
Found that Oracle Virtual column is similar to the the derived column with the combination/computed of fields in a general view with some additional features, it executes virtual column expression during query execution.

Besides general view, there is option to use Materialized View which will create separate Materialized view segment and separate execution overhead too.

I am trying to figure out to maintain read-only virtual column which will be computed up on inserting/updating fields automatically when commit happens. Can anyone help for this solution in Oracle 11gR2?

--Example:

1. `create table table1(id int, field1 varchar2(30),field2 varchar2(30),field3 varchar2(30),field4 varchar2(30),field5 varchar2(200));`
2. ....Direct path load will happen into id, field1, field2, field3 and field4 by ETL process...
3. `update table1 set field5=field1 || '#' || field2 || '#' || field3 || '#' || field4;`
4. `commit;`

In above example, I wish to populate field5 internally automatically once we perform #1, #2 and #4 without adding major execution time.

Comment: For such a simple expression, I don't see any benefit in actually storing this value. Just go with a virtual/computed column and you should be fine.

Comment: Did you actually test the performance impact? It don't think you will notice it.

Comment: Above update statement takes longer time when you have populated massive volume of data during step#2. I just wish to avoid update execution here.

Comment: Again: why do you think you need a *persisted* column? If you just create a regular computed column you *do* avoid the update execution. Do you have a performance problem when retrieving using a computed column?

Comment: Reasons:
1. Following SQL scripts need to refer concatenated field.
2. Looking to avoid update execution
3. Bypass logging

Comment: 1. Virtual Column is perfect for this 2. Virtual Columns need no update at all 3. Don't generate logging... I think you may have misunderstood how a virtual column works! Please read up on that

Comment: If you use a virtual column you **will** avoid the update execution.

Comment: @Falco - Remember that the data present in the virtual column is not stored in the database, instead it is dynamically evaluated which could be avoided if we have persistent concatenated field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I understand virtual column will avoid the update but it doesn't hold data, instead it's computed which requires CPU resource during runtime.

Comment: And how do you know that evaluating that really simple expression is a problem? Did you do performance test using it? Unless you are using that expression in a where clause and need it to be indexed to make the query fast, I'm pretty sure you will not notice and difference

Comment: I have not done performance test using virtual column in my context. As I have mentioned earlier, table1 is populated/appended by ETL process and referred field5 as an reference or descriptive column in the application, and there is no query which searches using any value against it. 

Virtual Column could give benefit of partitioning, btree index or function based index by concatenating all fields for making faster query.

Comment: Finally _ I would even think that a real column could actually be SLOWER than a virtual column, because of increased row-size and thus possibly increased I/O when accessing multiple rows. What is more - If you use the virtual Column with an Index it doesn't make any difference, since the Index stores the values and is used for access, so the virtual column is not even accessed when searching via Index!

Answer (score 1):

We can resolve the above problem by using the below query

```
 create table table1
 (id int, 
  field1 varchar2(30),
  field2 varchar2(30),
  field3 varchar2(30),
  field4 varchar2(30),
  field5 varchar2(200) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (field1 || '#' || field2 || '#' || field3 || '#' || field4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check carefully **why** you need the additional column.

I can speculate, that this is to optimize access using a predicates such as

```
WHERE field5 like '%#<search key>#%'
```

to avoid a complicated predicates with lot of **OR**s

If this is the reason, you may profit from *additional table* insted of additional concatenated column

```
create table HLPR
(id number,  /* FK to your table */
 field_no NUMBER,
 field_value  varchar2(30));
```

The same predicate as above you may formulate now with

```
 WHERE field_value = '<search key>'
```

i.e. you have all possibilities of FULL TABLE SCAN or index access to get a performant query.

Sorry if my speculation goes in a wrong direction, only my 0.02c